# Retriving RSA public key from hex string generated from x509certificate getpublickeystring method

Tags: c#, rsa

I've been developing a project involving digital signatures. I'm given a publickey generated through *getpublickeystring* method of x509Certificate2.

This is the given publickey

```
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
```

But I'm unable to construct a correct pem certificate from this.

This the code I have used to generate pem from the hex string.

```
byte[] certBytes = Enumerable.Range(0, certHex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(certHex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
string certPem = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
    Convert.ToBase64String(certBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
    .TrimEnd() + "\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
```

> Generated certPem

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBCgKCAQEA2PFlKAc4qCeqHSlg0J7KfqOSi8O2ukzwNL7+bgDbQ0eTuWwv0kEb4Ia2zkswRB0Y
3/N3SX+Z8EPnSywwVV0hV8KDjJ573VZvBjPMC+byZJJ4u4/hXrLUAgwIeyJS2O0CTdJgo6oH85nZ
Dr2nIr7+ytbXoBGjD5ATxK/j4Vul5bkCjeUQec3hJVVbguQmlpnmYti/GC3xc/zJATX8EXuCVL9w
Nv4KmwZnwCZujvlPnuYwygz2Ef8Lsrv9mae52cxsk9Jyp9yH/lnTXDTZSH8QOBecZXYRSZTJQvgm
FovfES3Rf8VyVoSudDWf7Yx1PR1/AauPWgcOk92JygybwlIMhQIDAQAB
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

But the result is failing when I use

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(certPem));
```

Going through some past questions I saw that rsa exponent and modulus values are separated using the`,` delimiter, but here, it is not present.

Kindly provide some insights to solve this issue.

**Edit**

Decryption Logic

```
csp = RSA.Create();
csp.ImportFromPem(certPem.ToCharArray());
var decryptedBytes = csp.Decrypt(encryptedData, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
```

Exception occurs during csp.Decrypt

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'Key does not exist.'
```

Comment: `certHex` is a hex encoded public key in PKCS#1 format. The code converts this to a PEM encoded public key, but with incorrect header/footer whose texts for a PKCS#1 key are *BEGIN/END RSA PUBLIC KEY*. The *CERTIFICATE* header/footer does not make a certificate out of this key. The import fails because the `X509Certificate2` ctor requires a certificate and not a key.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I could load this public key to System.Security.Cryptograhy RSA class to decrypt an encrypted data?

Comment: A PKCS#1 public key can be imported with [`ImportRSAPublicKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importrsapublickey?view=net-7.0) (requires the DER encoded key, i.e. your hex **de**coded `certHex`) or with [`ImportFromPem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importfrompem?view=net-7.0) (requires the PEM encoded key, i.e. your `certPem` with **fixed** header/footer). For the decryption itself apply `Decrypt()` (using the padding applied during encryption).

Comment: Hi, tried both methods and I keep getting key does not exist exception during the decrypt()

Comment: I missed in your comments that you want to **de**crypt data. For decryption you need the *private* key. The *public* key can only be used for **en**cryption.

Comment: With regard to *...involving digital signatures...* you presumably don't mean *decrypting*, but *verifying*.This is possible with the public key.  Then you have to use the `VerifyData()` or `VerifyHash()` method.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question the signature value is encrypted using the corresponding private key, which I have the public key of

Comment: Please see my last two comments. For verification, you need to use the appropriate methods (using the padding applied during signing).

Comment: Ok, I was trying to manually implement the process. Just curious on why I'm getting this exception though. Will use ```VerifyData()``` if this does not work

Comment: The *native* C# methods do not support this: `Encrypt()` requires a public key. If a private key is passed, the public key is extracted and a *regular* encryption (i.e. with the pulic key) is performed. `Decrypt()` requires a private key, if a public key is passed the *Key does not exist* exception is thrown, since from a public key naturally no private key can be derived.

Comment: So this is not possible?

Comment: AFAIK not with the native C# methods. Encryption and signing use different paddings. You need a library to *decrypt a signature with the public key* that supports modular exponentiation with the public key and handles the padding for signing (e.g. RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 for PKCS#1 v1.5) and not the one for encrypting (e.g. RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 for PKCS#1v1.5). At least if it is a signature according to [RFC8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017).

Comment: BouncyCastle/C# would be such a third-party library.