# Incorrect block exception during decryption bouncy castle

Tags: c#, .net-core, bouncycastle

I've been working on a project to verify digital signature of provided XML documents.

The document schema is as provided below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLReport>
   <INNER_CONTENT>----content----</INNER_CONTENT>
   <Signature>
      <SIGNALGO>SHA512</SIGNALGO>
      <KeyInfo>3082010A0282010100D8F165280...........</KeyInfo>
      <SignatureValue>{data}</SignatureValue>
      <HASH>{data}</HASH>
   </Signature>
</XMLReport>
```

So far, I've tried to decrypt the `SignatureValue` in the provided document using the public key constructed from the `KeyInfo` field. I'm using the BouncyCastle library to do the above, but it's been throwing me the below exception.

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: 'block incorrect'
```

The error occurs at the below code:

```
var decryptedBytes = decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes(segment), 0, segment.Length);
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Some help to solve this issue is much appreciated.

Edit:

```
public static string RsaDecryptWithPublic(string encryptedData, string publicKey) {
  var decryptedResult = string.Empty;
  try {
    Int32 EncryptedLength = 256;
    int len = encryptedData.Length;
    var length = len / EncryptedLength;

    var decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

    using(var txtreader = new StringReader(publicKey)) {
      var keyParameter = (AsymmetricKeyParameter) new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();

      decryptEngine.Init(false, keyParameter);
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    string resultData = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      string segment = encryptedData.Substring(i * EncryptedLength, EncryptedLength);
      try {
        var decryptedBytes = decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes(segment), 0, segment.Length);
        resultData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetString(decryptedBytes);
      } catch (Exception GenEx) {
        string error = GenEx.Message;
      }

      sb.Append(resultData);
    }
    decryptedResult = sb.ToString();
  } catch (Exception ex) {

  }
  return decryptedResult;
}
```

Comment: Post the full code and test data to reproduce the issue (one line of code makes it difficult to analyze the problem, keys may have different formats, etc.). Also it is unclear why you want to decrypt the signature and not verify it, which is unusual and not supported by every library (see also your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75092750/9014097)).

Comment: Hi @Topaco I've edited the question and used a third party library (bouncy castle) as you suggested from the previous question. The reason I'm not using verify method is because I'm unaware of how to pass in the public key value to the ```RSA.VerifyData``` method and manuel implementation seemed more straight forward

Comment: What .NET version are you running (key import support depends on it)? There are many ways to sign. Therefore, to implement verification (or decryption), the code for signing is needed, or at least test data, i.e. the fields `KeyInfo`, `SignatureValue` and `HASH`.

Comment: @Topaco I'm using .NET 6.0, also edited the question with field values

Comment: The data for `SignatureValue` and `HASH` looks very much like corrupted data to me. Usually binary data like signatures or hashes are encoded with a binary-to-text-encoding as string, e.g. Base64 or hexadecimal (like `KeyInfo`). Charset encodings like UTF-8 or similar corrupt such data. In this case of course verification fails.

Comment: ok, I was given these test samples in a .txt file. I used 1256 encoding to read them. Are there any issues that can occur apart from corrupted data?

Comment: Do not encode the data with Cp1256, but read the file with a hex editor and post the hex encoded or Base64 encoded data (or share the files somewhere). However, if the data has been decoded with a charset encoding at some point, it is probably *irreversibly* damaged. A necessary validity criterion is the lengths: The signature must be 256 bytes, the hash 64 bytes.

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/470dec5265d015bb035b031e03fde3e520230116110343/51e979 I've added the test file, pls note that I've removed main xml content as it contains sensitive data

Comment: I can't find an encoding that generates byte sequences of valid length from this data. Ask the sender side how to encode this data. Any reasonable design would use Base64 or hexadecimal, analogous to `KeyInfo`. Why isn't the same encoding used as for `KeyInfo`? Very obscure. Maybe the data is corrupted for some reason.

Comment: Much appreciated @Topaco I will confirm from the sender side